# What is the most efficient way to always make a database query that I know will only return a result very occasionally?

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I am trying to work out how to implement a new piece of functionality on my website. My site allows people to download things uploaded by members of a group. The new piece of functionality will allow 1 member of the group to be a 'super' user whos uploads cannot be downloaded. So at the moment my query (more or less) is -

```
SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE group = $groupid
```

I am thinking I will store the 'super' status of the member in the 'members' table so will probably look up this to get the member id of the super member before doing the query.

```
$all_group_members = SELECT members FROM groups WHERE group_id = $groupid
$super_member = SELECT memberid FROM members WHERE memberid IN ($all_group_members) AND super_status = 1
```

Then modify the query to be -

```
SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE group = $groupid AND uploader ! = $super_member
```

However there may not always be a super member in a group, so my question is is there a more effective way to do this, for example store the super members ids in the session cookie? What about storing the super user id in the group table - still involves doing a query -

```
SELECT super_user FROM groups WHERE groupid = $group_id
```

But atleast thats one less query.

Is there just no way around this - I know that there will only be a super user about 5% of the time so 95% of the time this will be wasted query. Perhaps the session cookie could store a **group_has_super_user** variable.

Any other ways of doing this that im missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, other group members can't download anything from my group's stuff. So, simply add a *downloadable* field to the *uploads*, and set it to

- 1, if a simple member has uploaded it, or
- 0, if a super member has.

Then the **only** query you have to run is:

```
SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE group = $groupid AND downloadable != 0
```

Also, if the membership is changing (e.g. someone else gets the super right), these flags should be recalculated in the group.

Don't forget to create index for (or set the primary key to) groupid + downloadable (or downloadable + groupid)!

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you explain the setting of primary key to groupid + downloadable? why is this important? thanks

Comment: If you don't create key, SQL server have to make a full table scan: it checks each record for the condition. When you indexing a table, SQL server creates some index files (whihch you can't see), which is used to list records in *sorted* order, instead of random order. So, using index, the SQL server can quickly find the first matching record, and stop the scan when first unmatching record found. You can try it yourself: make a list with your contact's name in random order and another one in alphabet order, then try to find a person in both: full table scan vs binary search. Which is faster?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE uploads (id, user_id, …)
CREATE TABLE groups (id, …)
CREATE TABLE group_users (group_id, user_id, is_super, …)

SELECT  u.*
FROM    group_users gu
JOIN    uploads u
ON      u.user_id = gu.user_id
WHERE   gu.group_id = $group_id
        AND gu.is_super = 0
```

Comment: +1 but answer is incomplete in absence of some words of description